# Do processing in separated threads with Activiti

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, activiti

With activiti it is possible to design parallel tasks, however these tasks are internally executed sequentially (by the same thread).

I need to execute tasks in a asynchronous way, and then "join" the tasks once they are finished.

The process is:

```
preparation -> execute task 1
            -> execute task 2 at the same time
      -> Then once both are finished, go one
```

It is a matter of optimization, because tasks 1 and 2 are web-service calls and may require a lot of time.

From everything I read, this is not possible with activiti. Using async tasks, it is not possible to join then properly (detect that both are finished). The first finished task is OK, but the second throws an OptimisticLockException and is restarted (which is not acceptable).

Maybe there is something I misunderstood and this is something possible or even easy??? Did anyone succeed in it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand your question clearly.
but Activiti does support Async processing.

To Join two Async processes you can create another task that will wait till both the Async tasks are completed.

Comment: This is exactly my question. I tried to put 2 async task into a parallel gateway, but it fails into an optimistic lock exception. Documentation explains that the first task finishing "wins" and the other tasks fails with aushc exception. According to your explanation, what kind of task should be used to join ask tasks?